# React Native - iOS subscription receipt verification (firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, native

currently I am working on a app but struggling to find since last two weeks the following:

I have react native iOS app with RN-iap for subscription.. and would like to implement receipt verification via cloud function at firebase.

I found a similar solution but its with SWIFT: https://www.loopwerk.io/articles/2020/storekit-webhooks-firestore/

can anybody please help me convert the code (swift below) into React Native ? really appreciate

or if any suitable example or lines please.

(I am using React native firebase).
I can able to fetch receipt and save in Firestore collection. Thanks in advance.

below are the codes:
FRONT END CALLING Cloud function

```js
import Firebase
import FirebaseFunctions
import Foundation

final class CloudFunction {
  private lazy var functions = Functions.functions()

  func validateReceipt(receipt: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let parameters = ["receipt": receipt]

    functions.httpsCallable("validateReceipt").call(parameters) { _, error in
      if let error = error {
        print(error)
      }

      completionHandler()
    }
  }
}
```

Cloud Function for above:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const db = admin.firestore();

const runtimeOpts = {
  memory: '1GB',
};

function validateAndStoreReceipt(url, options, userSnapshot) {
  return fetch(url, options).then(result => {
    return result.json();
  }).then(data => {
    if (data.status === 21007) {
      // Retry with sandbox URL
      return validateAndStoreReceipt('https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt', options, userSnapshot);
    }

    // Process the result
    if (data.status !== 0) {
      return false;
    }

    const latestReceiptInfo = data.latest_receipt_info[0];
    const expireDate = +latestReceiptInfo.expires_date_ms;
    const isSubscribed = expireDate > Date.now();

    const status = {
      isSubscribed: isSubscribed, 
      expireDate: expireDate, 
    };

    const appleSubscription = {
      receipt: data.latest_receipt,
      productId: latestReceiptInfo.product_id,
      originalTransactionId: latestReceiptInfo.original_transaction_id
    };

    // Update the user document!
    return userSnapshot.ref.update({status: status, appleSubscription: appleSubscription});
  });
}

exports.validateReceipt = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
  }

  if (!data.receipt) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'receipt is required');
  }

  // First we fetch the user
  const userSnapshot = await db.collection('users').doc(context.auth.uid).get();
  if (!userSnapshot.exists) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('not-found', 'No user document found.');
  }

  // Now we fetch the receipt from Apple
  let body = {
    'receipt-data': data.receipt,
    'password': 'MY_SECRET_PASSWORD',
    'exclude-old-transactions': true
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  };

  return validateAndStoreReceipt('https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt', options, userSnapshot);
});
```

continuation another cloud function:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();

const runtimeOpts = {
  memory: '1GB',
};

exports.appleWebhook = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Only allow POST requests
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
  }

  // Check for correct password
  if (req.body.password !== 'MY_SECRET_PASSWORD') {
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
  }

  const receipt = req.body.unified_receipt.latest_receipt_info[0];

  // Find the user with this stored transaction id
  const userQuerySnapshot = await db.collection('users')
    .where('appleSubscription.originalTransactionId', '==', receipt.original_transaction_id)
    .limit(1)
    .get();

  if (userQuerySnapshot.empty) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('not-found', 'No user found');
  }

  const expireDate = +receipt.expires_date_ms;
  const isSubscribed = expireDate > Date.now();

  const status = {
    isSubscribed: isSubscribed, 
    expireDate: expireDate, 
  };

  const appleSubscription = {
    receipt: req.body.unified_receipt.latest_receipt,
    productId: receipt.product_id,
    originalTransactionId: receipt.original_transaction_id,
  };

  // Update the user
  return userQuerySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({ status: status, appleSubscription: appleSubscription }).then(function() {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  });
});
```